# Printing simple SQL comparsion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm comparing two variables which I'd like to be printed to the console like so:

```
==Full Ex Vat==
true
```

Currently the code to do this is:

```
print '==Full Ex Vat=='
print case when
@aTotalExVat = @sTotalExVat
then 'true' else 'false' end
```

which I feel isn't as elegant as it could be.

Any tips?

Comment: Seems fine to me. Not sure what bugs you with this. I'd write the second `print` statement on a single line though.

Comment: I have a few of these.  I'm looking for a way to tidy up and hopefully be able to reuse.

Comment: To make it more reusable, maybe you want to put in a stored proc

Answer (score 4):

SQL uses three valued logic.

When one of the operands is null the expression evaluates to `UNKNOWN` not false. Your current code does not take account of this and can be altered as below to do so.

```
PRINT CASE
        WHEN @aTotalExVat = @sTotalExVat THEN 'true'
        WHEN @aTotalExVat <> @sTotalExVat THEN 'false'
        ELSE 'unknown'
      END
```

If you wanted to treat `NULL = NULL` as true and `NULL = any not null value` as false you could use

```
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(5) = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT @aTotalExVat 
                                               INTERSECT 
                                               SELECT @sTotalExVat) 
                                   THEN 'true'
                                   ELSE 'false'
                               END;

PRINT '==Full Ex Vat==';
PRINT @Message;
```

On SQL Server 2012 there are a couple of new functions that shorten the above somewhat

```
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(5) = IIF(EXISTS(SELECT @aTotalExVat 
                                         INTERSECT 
                                         SELECT @sTotalExVat), 
                                  'true', 
                                  'false');

PRINT CONCAT('==Full Ex Vat==', CHAR(13), ( CHAR(10) ), @Message);
```